# Replace DPDT on-on-on switch with relays

Tags: relay, dpdt

I want to control via Arduino a peltier cooler/heater that uses a DPDT on-on-on switch to set the voltage at the terminals of the peltier cell to +12 V, 0V or -12V. I have measured the voltages at the six terminals of the switch and the voltages in the three configurations are as shown in this figure:
[image: Voltages at the terminals of the dpdt on-on-on switch]
The terminals at the top and at the bottom of the switch are set to either 0V or 12V as in the figure (voltages written in black). The position of the switch forms the colored junctions that set the voltages in the central terminals.

I would like to use an Arduino to control the voltages of the central terminals in a way analogous to the switch. I was planning on doing this by using relays, but I'm unsure how to do the wiring and if I need a 4-channel relay of if a 2-channel relay is sufficient. Do you have suggestions? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Breaking this down... controlling this via a micro needs to define 3 states:

- off (no voltage across the Peltier)
- cool (0, +12)
- heat (+12, 0)

I think this can be simplified as two GPIO bits, and two SPDT relays. Why *two* relays? SPDT types are common, inexpensive and reliable, so it’s more convenient to model the on-off-on using a pair of these.

So here’s what that looks like:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fDsEOd.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This works as follows:

- COOL, HEAT low: (-) = 12V, (+) = 12V
- COOL high: (-) = 0V, (+) = 12V
- HEAT high: (-) = 12V, (+) = 0V
- COOL, HEAT high: (-) = 0V, (+) = 0V (probably does no harm, but check)

The relay coils draw a bit of current, about 10 ~ 30mA depending on the type. That's very small compared to what the Peltier draws, so not even significant.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that 2-relay module should work for you.  Keep in mind that one or both coils may be energized for long periods so it's not very efficient, but it should function fine.  Ultimately you would want a set of MOSFETS in an H-bridge arrangement, but using relays saves you the trouble of dealing with shoot-through, and is much easier to wire.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a scheme, using a diode matrix, push button switches, magnetic latch relays and a 'H' bridge. Freewheeling diodes, for the relay coils, and LED indicators are not shown.

[image]

S1, S2 and S3 are pushbutton switches which select '+12V', '-12V' and 'Off'.

[image]

Being latch relays the coils are not kept continuously energised.